# Draw image using image pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, mfc

I want to draw image(bmp) using an image pointer by VS2005(MFC).

But I don't know how to draw an image using `image pointer`.

Below is my code:

```
PVOID m_pBuffer;
m_pBuffer = lBuffer->GetDataPointer(); //lBuffer is offered parameter by Camera Company.
                                       //and GetDataPointer() funcion is 'A pointer to the memory pointer'
```

How do I draw an image using `image pointer`?
(ex. use `GDI`, `GDI+`, `CImage`..)

Comment: I tried to GDI, GDI+, CImage, HBITMAP, BITMAP...
But all conditions was failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what you want to do with it have a look at both [CreateBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/432f18e2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [CreateDIBSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To use [CreateBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/432f18e2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `lpBits` is where you pass in your `m_pBuffer`. Make sure the bitmap is the same format as your data!

For a 24bit BMP at 800x600:

```
HBITMAP MyBmp = CreateBitmap(800, 600, 1, 24, m_pBuffer);
```